# Addition reaction of alkenes

Tags: c-c-addition

During an addition reaction of an alkene, how does a double bond break to form two bonds with the two atoms of the reactant plus a bond between the carbon atoms? Not sure if this is a silly question or not, but if it’s a double bond, how does it end up forming three bonds?

Comment: Well, you add *something*, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities to explain this addition reaction. It could be an ionic mechanism or a radical mechanism. I only explain here the radical mechanism, because it is quickly done. You should know that doublets or bonds are made of two electrons. Imagine that for some reason the $2$nd bond of $\ce{R2C=CR2}$ is suddenly broken, then closed, then broken, and so on. When it is broken it becomes $\ce{·R2C-CR2·}$, with two free electrons, one on each carbon atom. If by chance a molecule $\ce{H2}$ or $\ce{Cl2}$ is present in the vicinity, and is also broken maybe by a ultra-violet light, the $ \ce{2 H·}$ or the two $\ce{Cl·}$ may recombine. But they may also recombine with the free electrons on the "opened" alkene molecule. This will produce an addition of $\ce{H2}$ (or $\ce{2H}$) or of $\ce{Cl2}$ (or $\ce{2 Cl}$) on the alkene. Sorry for the "serious" chemists who will read this simplified "theory". It works well with ordinary high school students, who are not scientifically inclined.